# After login to a server using a ZnClient post request, how can I send a file to another server in pharo?

Tags: pharo

Basically I used a ZnClient post request with auth which logged me in the server containing a list of file data.I need to transfer one file. How can I make another post to send a file to another server in pharo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you want but to send (upload) a file via `multipart/form-data`:

```smalltalk
ZnClient new
   url: 'http://another-server/form.html';
   addPart: (ZnMimePart
              fieldName: 'file'
              fileNamed: '/path/to/file.txt');
   post.
```

Above assumes that `form.html` on *another server* has a `<form>` similar to this:

```html
<form action="form-handler" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="file"/> 
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I meant after login, keeping the same session and then make a post for sending a file with name and value as the form.html above.Instead I used formAt add for each input label. It worked fine thanks. Do you know how to keep the session refreshing for certain amount of time?

Comment: @ludo - The session expiration is controlled by the server.  Unless the service provides some kind of session API then all you can do to keep it alive is to keep polling it.